# cv2 Python disable GUI bar on Debian Linux (Raspberry Pi)

Tags: python, linux, opencv

I am trying to dig around the openCv documentation but can't find a function call to disable the GUI status bar. Any suggestions? I am simply using the example:

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('messi5.jpg',0)
cv2.imshow('image',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3useme345mdkmaz/screen.png?dl=0)

Comment: I think such a feature is not available in OpenCV gui.

Comment: going to post a rough solution
'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had figured a somewhat constrained approach (that works for my means) is to have the images in fullscreen with this opencv call: '

```
cv2.setWindowProperty("window", cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN, cv2.cv.CV_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN)
```